# Maximum number of alarm clocks

Tags: alarm

My HTC One (Android 4.3) told me that I can only have 10 alarm clocks at maximum and that I should delete one before adding a new one. Why, and is it possible to have more than ten?

Comment: Why: That's the number they decided on. Can you have more, possibly, there are paid alarms that claim to allow more than 10, but I can't vouch for any.

Comment: There are a _ton_ of alarm clock apps in the Play Store.

Comment: Okay, if it is a constraint of the app than I could just switch to another. I thought that it possibly is a constraint of the android system cannot handling more alarms.

Comment: Oh don't worry, it's *definitely* not a constraint of the OS. That'd be paramount to Windows setting an arbitrary limit to the number of web bookmarks you can save in Firefox.

Comment: There's the alarm app, then there's HTC's modified version to further muddy things. I'd say try the Play Store as the others have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [Timely Alarm Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely). I've never tried more than 10 alarms but I guess it should be worth a try. It's free after all & extremely sexy.

Also you should try adding calender events instead of alarms and change the sound to something loud.

Comment: It is owned by Google now, afaik it only does 10. I haven't used it in a while though so worth a test. The calendar idea is also a good one!

Comment: This app is amazing. I tested it and it accepts more than 10 alarms. Don't know how reliable it is, but I will see. thx for tips and hints

Comment: My bad! Good to know. I figured once Google got their hands on it the usual restrictions would apply!

Comment: I use Timely. I rather like it and even ponied up for the ability to sync alarms between my devices.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have more than ten (alarms)?

Maybe not with HTC clock, but yes it is possible.

As mentioned by [dotVezz in the comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62110/maximum-number-of-alarm-clocks#comment84107_62110), *"it's definitely not a constraint of the OS"*.

Android doesn't set any restrictions regarding how many alarms they can store/handle, even on per-app basis. A counter-example to OP's case: a stock clock on Nexus 4 (Android 5.0) can have 15+ alarms (I stopped adding after 15 alarms).

If you want to have more than 10 alarms, then you can just search it since *"there are a ton of alarm clock apps in the Play Store."* As already mentioned in [other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/62115/44325), [Timely Alarm Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely) supports more than 10 alarms.

> Why (is it impossible to have more than ten alarms with HTC clock)?

I can't really answer this without speculating as this is a decision made by HTC. Some possibilities that I could think off:

1. Less alarms are easier to manage
2. Less alarms won't hit the OS performance.

But for the technical part, Android is open-source and anyone can customize it as they like, including adding the alarm restriction on the clock app.